# Recaptcha - not getting right

Tags: recaptcha

I'm not getting recaptcha image correctly..It says invalid domain key. I actually registered recaptcha in google account for localhost. Can I use recaptcha on localhost? Can someone explain to em why I'm getting this error? Are thee keys keyed in correctly, please?
[image]

The key from google:
[image]

ANd in my joomla backend, I have to key in public and private key:Where I assumed Site key = public key while Secret Key is Private Key.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you go to this [link](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list) and check your domain is there and you have the correct keys? Also, does this error appear on specific actions (e.g. when submitting the feedback form) or does it always happen when you load any page with a captcha on it?

I suggest you to go through this [reCAPTCHA FAQs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq)  link.. It will help you

And easiest solution is delete it and register new key. You will be after that.

And one more thing is that secret key is private kind of thing. You do not need to provide it here. Walk on safe side.

Comment: it happens always when I load any page with Recaptcha on it.

Comment: solved by creating a new key...I registered a wrong domain